# Alternative for clip-path: inset() in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: html, css

I am making an application with JSF and Primefaces, I am facing an issue in one of my html elements.

***This is the code.***

```
<div style='background-repeat: repeat-x;background- 
image:url("/ASQ/resources/img/xxx_grey.png");width:300px;height:75px;' > 
</div>

<div style='background-repeat: repeat-x;background- 
image:url("/ASQ/resources/img/xxx_green.png");margin- 
top:-75px;width:300px;height:75px; clip-path:inset(0px #{300 - 
((((pollData.generalSat * 100)/5) * 300)/100)}px 0px 0px);'></div>
```

`#{300 - ((((pollData.generalSat * 100)/5) * 300)/100)}` is a number I get from my bean and I use to clip the background.

As you can see, I use clip-path:inset() and my application must run with Internet Explorer 8, therefore, clip-path is not working, I have searched and haven't found anything about IE8, only about newer versions and all the info found tells to use SVG instead but this is not supported in IE8 either. Currently, it works perfectly with Chrome and Firefox.

So, is there any way to make this work with IE 8?

Comment: I think the only way is to stop using IE8 ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif Sadly, it is not possible, this is a coporative application and the company needs it to be used with IE8.

Comment: @Pete SVG is not supported by IE8.

Comment: I think it will be easier to convince the Company to stop using IE8 than finding a solution for IE8 ... by they way can you show us what is the needed output ? maybe we find a workaround without clip-path

Comment: Should you not tell the company to stop using outdated unsupported products? surely that is a big security issue for them

Comment: I did and different departments have changed to IE10 or IE11 but some of them still use IE8, and I was told to make it work with that browser, until further notice, I have to make compatible with IE8.

Comment: Make it compatible - doesn't mean it has to be pixel perfect, usually just functional - you need to explain that if you want to use old browsers, you don't get modern functionality / design.  You need to punish users of old browsers to get them to upgrade

Comment: I know but they liked that feature I used, and my boss is a bit relunctant to use an alternative, if there isn't any way to adapt it to IE8, I will let him know it needs to be change but first I have to run out of options, even if I have to use JS to make it work.

Comment: IE8 will take :after that you can reset with ::after for other browser. to insert an absolute pseudo that you can clip wia `clip:rect(X X X X );`  IE8 also take conditionnal comment to restyle the div and clip a pseudo.  example of the idea https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/aGYJNZ (no CSS filtering added nor conditionnal comments) see https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/clip

Comment: Best advice is to accept that there is no solution for this in IE8. The truth is that often times there is a way of doing it, either via ugly hacks or obscure proprietary IE features, but consider your time and effort to learn how to do it, then to do it, and then to support the your creation... it just isn't worth it, either to the company (cost) or to you (learning obsolete tech isn't a good career move).

Comment: Render it server side in headless chrome if you want to use clip path or just build and SVG and render it to a PNG pic that will be displayed in IE8. There is no way to make it work client side only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @G-Cyr answer I came with a solution that works just fine.

I changed mi HTML to this:

```
<div class="sat-gen">
    <div class="sat-gen2"></div>
</div>
```

And I added this CSS to my XHTML.

```
.sat-gen{
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-image:url("/ASQ/resources/img/xxx_grey.png");
    width:300px;
    height:75px;
}

.sat-gen > .sat-gen2{
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-image:url("/ASQ/resources/img/xxx_green.png");
    width:300px;
    height:75px;
    position:absolute;
    clip: rect(0px #{((((datosEncuesta.valoracionSatisfaccionGeneral * 100)/5) * 300)/100)}px 75px 0px);
}
```

Since I am using a value from my backing bean I had to add all the CSS in a internal CSS sheet, so you have to keep this in mind in case you are using a value from a bean (inline style is also possible), if not, you can use the CSS in the best way you want.